# Kendo treeview on hover

Tags: angularjs, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am working on Kendo treeview using angular and typescript.Is there any event for onHover in kendo treeview. I want to take the selected element using on hover event.

```
<div kendo-tree-view k-data-source="treeData" k-data-text-field="['directiveItem.elementId']" k-expand="expandtree" k-change="changetree" k-drag-and-drop="true k-drop="onDrop" ng-click="ctrlOpen($event)">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Telerik page, the events I see listed are: change, check, collapse, dataBound, drag, dragend, dragstart, drop, expand, navigate, select.

no onHover but please check the autoscroll configuration. It may have the solution you are looking for.  https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview/configuration/autoscroll